# How to create a row for user in another related table when the user is created in laravel?

Tags: sql, laravel

I need to create a row in a related table. This is a hasOne and belongsTo relationships. 
A user hasOne profile
A profile belongsTo user

I want to create a profile row once the user has been created.

```
public function store(UserRequest $request)
{
    $user= new User();
    User::create($request->all());
    Profile::create([
        'user_id' => $user->user_id,
    ]);
    return redirect()->route('users.index')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
public function store(UserRequest $request)
{
    $user = User::create($request->all());
    $user->profile()->create([]);

    return redirect()->route('users.index')
}
```

You have to have `hasOne` relation method in user's class:

```
public function profile()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Profile::class);
}
```

This for update is not working; Is there a solution

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $input = $request->all();
    $employee = Employee::findorfail($id);
    $update = $employee->update($input);
    $employee->personaldetail()->update(['employee_id' => $employee->employees_id,]);
    return redirect()->route('employees.index')->with('message','Employee has been updated');
}
```

Comment: What would be the method to update it. I tried replace create with update?

Comment: I am struggling with the update. The code I have added above for update is resetting the relationship employee_id to NULL in db.

Answer (score 0):

you can use events(observer) in laravel for doing your work when User created in any where of your project.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent#observers

Answer (score 0):

Use [Model Observers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent#observers).

You can declare an observer to `created` event, and create the profile there.

```
public function creating($model)
{
    // Create your related profile.
    // Note that profile relationship must be defined at your model class
    $model->profile()->create();

    return true;
}
```

This observer may be created either on a Model Observer Class, or declared on model boot.